# lightweiht charts hide and appear candles

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, lightweight-charts

Is there a way in python or js that I can make the present candles disappear until I can reach a point in the past? My goal is to make the candles disappear from right to left with the left arrow key and reappear with the right arrow key.

The information is extracted from a .csv